# How do I get a subsite to inherit the main masterpage?

Tags: master-page

I have a masterpage (copy of v4.master) and I added a link to a custom css.  when I create a new site it does not pick up the correct master page.  How do I fix this? thanks

Comment: In what edition you have created this master page? I mean 2007 or 2010?

Comment: Is this for publishing sites? We only use Team sites, how do I manage ensuring that all subsites utilize our custom master page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can turn on the Publishing feature for the Root site and in the Site Action -> Site Settings -> Master Pages you will see a screen like below:

[image]

Here you can specify to inherit the root-site master page for sub-sites!

Also, if its just a CSS that you have used - at the bottom you can see an option to Specify a CSS to be used by this publishing site and its sub-sites!

Read answer from David-Andrew-Smith on [this URL](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/e7ea77ec-7e9a-437e-9a4b-f5e958d6ec37) for detailed info

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks the odd thing is my sub site does not give me the option to pick "Master page" under the Look and Feel section.  I only have Title,description,and icon -- Tree view -- Site theme --Navigation.

Comment: Never mind I see I was to check the box at the bottom. All works great. Thanks.

Comment: As Arsalan said, you need to activate the publishing feature for the link to the master page to show.

Comment: Jjp, if the answer was helpful please mark that as Answer for the question! Thanks.

Comment: The comment about checkbox is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work when the subsite uses a different template. Is there a way to force the master page inheritance in that case ?

Comment: @M3HD1 please ask a separate question where you can link this question as reference

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri Here is a different quastion if you can help [Inherit Master Page when the subsite uses different template](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122548/inherit-master-page-when-the-subsite-uses-different-template)