# Can I force subsites to use the Master Page of a custom theme?

Tags: 2007, custom-masterpage, theme

First off, this issue is with a Custom Theme & Master Page in Sharepoint 2007.

Is there a way to force subsites to re-pull the Master Page from the Custom Theme within the 12 Hive? Due to lack of knowledge I've manually changed a couple subsites masterpages and would like to restore the Custom Theme Site-Wide.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, If you are familiar with Powershell you can use this script to force subsites to use custom master page,

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://fba.contosotest.com/dv1

$site | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object { $_.MasterUrl = "/dv1/_catalogs/masterpage/custom_v4.master";$_.Update() }

$site.Dispose()
```

Otherwise you can use publishing feature, as stated in [Another similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/how-do-i-get-a-subsite-to-inherit-the-main-masterpage).

If your sites not publishing sites then You need to set the
System Master page to the one you want to use to have that applied to your
non-publishing sites.

For more information check this link out

[Inheriting Masterpage Subsites Moss 2007](http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/inheriting-masterpage-subsites-moss2007-9948.aspx)

Hope it helps.