# Subsite not inheriting master page from parent until manual intervention

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, publishing

I have a SharePoint 2013 publishing site collection that has a custom master page for look and feel. I created a site template (also a publishing site) that inherits the master page from the parent. When I create a new subsite using that template the master page doesn't take effect until I manually go to Site Settings | Master Page and flip the radio buttons from Inherit to Specify and back. Why?

Comment: The site template you have was taken before the new master page was applied to entire site collection or after.

Answer (score 2):

Just a workaround if you have access to EventReceivers:

Write a `WebProvisioned` Receiver and set the `MasterUrl` property of the new `SPWeb` object to the `MasterUrl` of your parent (or whatever Web you know of that is using the correct MasterPage).

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply the master page on site which is created from custom site template. Either you can use event receiver or you need to modify the master page from the template (Extract template and update default seattle.master).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the onet.xml inside the solution file. You will have to extract the .wsp from the solution gallery then edit the onet.xml so that the master page urls looks like this:

MasterUrl="/_catalogs/masterpage/MyCustom.master"

note the first slash!!!

then use makecab to create a new cabinet file.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411440/makecab-create-a-cab-file-from-all-the-files-in-a-folder

Answer (score -3):

Browse to the master page settings, check off the box that says "Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting", and click OK.

A similar question has been answered here:
[How do I get a subsite to inherit the main masterpage?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/how-do-i-get-a-subsite-to-inherit-the-main-masterpage)

Comment: Clearly not a answer, as the topic title already clarifies the topic starter knows how to do this manually. The problem is that you have to 'reset all subsites to inherit the master page' every time you create a new subsite.