# Site collection and inherit master page in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: master-page, site-collection, site

I've created a web application at : test.mycompany.net
Then I created a root site collection at : test.mycompany.net (publishing portal template)
and 3 site collections :

1. test.mycompany.net/dev (develop template)
2. test.mycompany.net/my (mysite template)
3. test.mycompany.net/team (team site template)

My questions are:

- Is the test.mycompany.net site collection parent for the three other sites?

I've created a custom master page and using it for test.mycompany.net but the three other sites  aster page did't inherit it.

- Why didn't they get my custom master page?
- What should I do to get this functionality?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47328/how-do-i-get-a-subsite-to-inherit-the-main-masterpage

Comment: didn't work!!! . I don't see the checkbox. And there is no answer for the question : Is the test.mycompany.net site collection parent for the three other sites?

Comment: Are you creating site collections or new subsites? like /dev, /my and /team looks like you are creating subsites.. If that's the case the above should work.. But if they are site collections, then they are completely independent from root site collection and you need to apply masterpage on each

Comment: I create the site collection, because there is no template alow me to create site collection with subsite consist of these (mysite, team site, wiki) template. Right?

Comment: I think you can create subsite for Team site and Wiki.. But Mysite has to be a site collection.. Not sure of course, but I will give it a try.. 2013 or 2010 ? which version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using 2013 :)

Comment: I've check it. We can create sub site team and learn, but can't do it with my site . But I got problem when I change masterpage in my site collection, my learn site inherit but my team site doesn't . (even I've set it to inherit master page of parent in setting, both learn and team ) I don't know why

Answer (score 2):

A Site Collection cannot have a Parent Site Collection, A Site Collection can only have child Sub-Sites.

So to answer your questions:

1. 'test.mycompany.net' is not a parent to the other site collections.
2. It didn't inherit because there is no parent-child relationship. Only subsites would be able to inherit the masterpage.
3. In order to 'share' a masterpage, you would need to add the masterpage to a feature that you could activate on all 4 site collections. Then any changes made to the masterpage would be applied to all 4 sites.

These diagrams may help explain the SharePoint Hierachy: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC413942.jpg

Here's a walkthrough of adding your masterpage as a feature:
http://amjadk.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-create-a-master-page-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/